# How to resolve cypress error when installing first time

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

Error: Cannot find module 'cypress-xpath' from 'D:\Automation Code\Cypress\cypress-ui-automation\cypress\support'
at D:\Automation Code\Cypress\cypress-ui-automation\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
at process (D:\Automation Code\Cypress\cypress-ui-automation\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:173:43)
at ondir (D:\Automation Code\Cypress\cypress-ui-automation\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:188:17)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have missed the install of `cypress-xpath`.

If you are installing with npm:

```js
npm install -D cypress-xpath
```

or if you are installing with yarn:

```js
yarn add cypress-xpath --dev
```

You clearly already have the the require statement in `\cypress\support` since that is the first path in the error stack.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the [cypress-xpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-xpath) plugin is already installed, Under `cypress/support/e2e.js` you have to add this:

```js
require('cypress-xpath');
```